# Recognize a HTTPS-connection with a foreign certificate

Tags: java, https, certificate, httpurlconnection, urlconnection

I want to get a connection via HTTPS to a Server. The Server uses a unsigned certificate.
I found a solution to download those certificates from sun.

That is my Code:

```
{
    final char[] CertPassphrase = "changeit".toCharArray(); 
    private boolean installCert() throws
                             KeyStoreException, NoSuchAlgorithmException,
                             CertificateException, KeyManagementException,
                             IOException {
    boolean isCertInstalled = true;
    File file = new File("jcacerts");
    if (!file.isFile())
    {
        char SEP = File.separatorChar;
        File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + SEP + "lib" + SEP + "security");
        file = new File(dir, "jssecacerts");
        if (!file.isFile())
        {
            file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
        }
    }
    InputStream in = new FileInputStream(file);
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    ks.load(in, CertPassphrase);
    in.close();
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    TrustManagerFactory tmf =
            TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm());
    tmf.init(ks);
    X509TrustManager defaultTrustManager = (X509TrustManager) tmf.getTrustManagers()[0];
    SavingTrustManager tm = new SavingTrustManager(defaultTrustManager);
    context.init(null, new TrustManager[]
           {
               tm
           }, null);
    SSLSocketFactory factory = context.getSocketFactory();
    SSLSocket socket = (SSLSocket) factory.createSocket(this.getStrUrl(), this.getPort() );
    socket.setSoTimeout(10000);

    try
    {
        socket.startHandshake();
        socket.close();
    } catch (SSLException e)
    {
        isCertInstalled = false;
    }
    if(!isCertInstalled){
        X509Certificate[] chain = tm.chain;
        if (chain == null)
        {
           return true;
        }
        BufferedReader reader =
           new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

        System.out.println("Certificat from "+this.getStrUrl()+". [Enter] to download, [q] to quit!");
        String line = reader.readLine().trim();
        if(line.length()==0){
            for(int i=0; i<chain.length; i++){
                X509Certificate cert = chain[i];
                String alias = this.getStrUrl() + "-" + (i + 1);
                ks.setCertificateEntry(alias, cert);

                OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream("jssecacerts");
                ks.store(out, this.CertPassphrase);
                out.close();
                System.out.println("Added certificate to keystore 'jcacerts'");
            }
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }
    }else
       return true;
}

private HttpsURLConnection openHttpsConnection(){
    try{
        if(this.installCert()){
            return (HttpsURLConnection)this.getUrl().openConnection();
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Zertifikat heruntergeladen");
            return null;
        }
    }catch (KeyStoreException e){
         System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (CertificateException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (KeyManagementException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e){
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return null;
}

private void closeHttpsConnection(HttpsURLConnection con){
    con.disconnect();
}

public void print_content(){
    HttpsURLConnection con = this.openHttpsConnection();
    try{
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
        String input;
        while ((input = br.readLine()) != null){
            System.out.println(input);
        }
        br.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public Https(String Url)            { this.setUrl(Url); }

private static class SavingTrustManager implements X509TrustManager
{

   private final X509TrustManager tm;
   private X509Certificate[] chain;

   SavingTrustManager(X509TrustManager tm)
   {
       this.tm = tm;
   }

   public X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers()
   {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }

   public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
           throws CertificateException
   {
       throw new UnsupportedOperationException();
   }

   public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
           throws CertificateException
   {
       this.chain = chain;
       tm.checkServerTrusted(chain, authType);
   }
}
```

In my opinion, the certificate is downloaded completely. But if I try to read from the Input-Stream, following Exceptions are thrown:

> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException:
>   java.security.cert.CertificateException: No name matching *url* found

Does someone know the correct solution for my problem or can otherwise help me?

Comment: I'm very surprised about the certificate passphrase -- you should only need a passphrase on a _private_ certificate, not on the public certificate. And it seems so strange to me that the code to store the certificate is in the same block as the code to perform the TLS session initiation. As for the "no name matching url" problem, what hostname is in the certificate and what hostname is in the URL?

Comment: The passphrase is for the Java-Keystore, to storage all certificates. Java has some certificates from Certificate Authorities. But the problem is, that if I get a certificate, which isn't signed from a CA java and isn't in the keystore, java throws a SSL-Handshake-Exception. So the only way to make it run, is to add the certificate in the java keystore, i think. Furthermore in a TLS session the server sends you a X509-certificate!

Comment: by the way, i missed to mention, that the hostname from the certificate equals the hostname from the url! But i don't know, wether the hostname IN the certificate!